# Garbage when listening to serial

Tags: serial, atmega328, uart

This is the atmega328p code that is supposed to send a predefined message repeatedly.

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUD 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALLER (((F_CPU / (BAUD * 16UL))) - 1)

void USART_init(void) {
    UBRR0H = (uint8_t) (BAUD_PRESCALLER >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t) (BAUD_PRESCALLER);
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (3 << UCSZ00);
}

void USART_send(unsigned char data) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

unsigned char USART_receive(void) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)));
    return (unsigned char) UDR0;
}

void USART_putstring(char *StringPtr) {
    while (*StringPtr != 0x00) {
        USART_send((unsigned char) *StringPtr);
        StringPtr++;
    }
}

char String[] = "Hello world!!";

int main(void) {
    USART_init();
    while (1) {
        USART_putstring(String);
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I try and listen to my serial port `screen /dev/tty.wchusbserial141120 9600`, only unicode nonsense comes back.

```cpp
���
```

I am not quite sure what's the issue here.

Comment: Repeatedly send the character U non-stop and examine the TX waveform with an oscilloscope. If it's not 4800Hz you have a baud rate problem.

Comment: Might want to add the wiring. Might be missing something there.

Comment: Your program works as expected on an Uno (I would just add `\r\n` at the end of the message). How are you clocking your ATmega?

Comment: Do you have correct F_CPU in Makefile? Is the DIV8 fuse disabled?